# What parameter type to use in Java/converting between Collection and Object array?

Tags: java

I'm doing a school assignment where I need to pass an array into a method. The array declaration is as follows:

```
  static Object[] myArray = new String[8];
```

It is called here (Proj04Runner is the class we are asked to create for the assignment):

```
   Proj04Runner runner = new Proj04Runner();
   myArray = runner.runA(myArray);
```

I tried to make a method in my Proj04Runner class called runA, but I keep getting error messages. I have tried:

```
   Collection runA(Object[] myArray){
```

and

```
   Collection runA(Collection myArray){
```

but get error messages both times. The error messages are, respectively:

```
   Proj04.java:60: error: incompatible types: Collection cannot be converted to Object[]

   Proj04.java:60: error: incompatible types: Object[] cannot be converted to Collection
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: So your instructor gave you `static Object[] myArray = new String[8];` ?  If so, that's pretty wacky.  That's a kinda scary line of code.

Comment: Steve yes, that is the code the professor gave me. He does use a loop to fill it with String values but I'm still struggling to get it to properly pass into my method.

Comment: Sounds like you need to implement `Object[] runA(Object[] myArray)`, but why it isn't at least `String[] runA(String[] myArray)`, I can't imagine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to assign the result back to `myArray`. You can't do that. Because the type of `myArray` is `static Object[]`. You fix it by defining a new variable to hold the result. Like,

```
Collection myCollection = runner.runA(myArray);
```

Note: It's a bad idea to use rawtypes in Java. `Collection` is a generic type. It should be some kind of `Collection<Type>`. Also, in `Proj04Runner`  it should be

```
Collection runA(Object[] myArray) { // <-- takes an `Object[]`
```

Finally, you haven't shown much code. But you are running `Proj04` (not `Proj04Runner`).

Comment: Forgive me for not explaining enough. The professor gives us a file to run called Proj04, which we are NOT allowed to edit, and we have to write a class called Proj04Runner which makes Proj04 produce a certain result. runA is supposed to sort the values in myArray, which is defined in Proj04. I'm sure this sounds confusing without having it all in front of you... But thank you for clarrifying that my parameter does need to be the object array.

Comment: Yes, when given `Object[] myArray`. Again, without seeing the code involved it's difficult to answer more concretely. You should probably follow up with your professor.